# Bootstrap Modal use from other Component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-bootstrap

This is **MapContainer.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { GoogleMap, LoadScript, Marker} from '@react-google-maps/api';


const MapContainer = () => {

    const [ currentPosition, setCurrentPosition ] = useState({});
  
    const success = position => {
      const currentPosition = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      }
      setCurrentPosition(currentPosition);
    };
    
    useEffect (() => {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
    })

    const mapStyles = {        
        height: "100vh",
        width: "100%"};
 
  
  return (
     <LoadScript googleMapsApiKey='AIzaSyA40-c3DnhRdFQ5In8xPdTgQSUne1UFhZI'>
       <GoogleMap mapContainerStyle={mapStyles} zoom={13} center={currentPosition}>
          {    
          currentPosition.lat &&
            ( 
              <Marker onClick={""} position={currentPosition}/> 
            )          
          } 
        </GoogleMap>
        
     </LoadScript>
  )
}

export default MapContainer;
```

And This is **ModalBootstrap.js**

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import MapContainer from '../MapContainer/MapContainer';


function Example() {
    const [show, setShow] = useState (false);
  
    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
  
    return (
      <>
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
          Launch demo modal
        </Button>
  
        <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
              Close
            </Button>
            <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
              Save Changes
            </Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </>
    );
  }
  
  render (<Example />);

  export default Example;
```

I want to show the 'Modal' when I click on the Marker [in MapContainer.js].I also want to pass the value of latitude and longitude from **MapContainer.js to ModalBootstrap.js**. I want to pass those datas when I click on the Marker. When I click on the Marker a modal will be pop up and it will show the current latitude and longitude of the location. I've implemented the google map successfully. But couldn't pass the value to the ModalBootStrap.js and show the Modal when I click the Marker. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Switch your modal to be controlled from a parent state instead of having an internal state, such that the state & state setter for the modal `show` prop can be controlled by passing these state as props down to the Map Component. An example of these is you can have your `Example` component & `MapContainer` component have the same parent component

```
export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  const [currentPosition, setCurrentPosition] = useState({});

  return (
    <>
      <MapContainer
        currentPosition={currentPosition}
        setCurrentPosition={setCurrentPosition}
        handleShow={handleShow}
      />
      <Example
        currentPosition={currentPosition}
        show={show}
        handleClose={handleClose}
        handleShow={handleShow}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Back on your `MapContainer` component just update it to use the `handleShow` prop for the `onClick` prop of `Marker` so it will control the opening of the modal. As for the `currentPosition` state, we can also moved this state up since this will also be used by the modal as to display the Latitude & Longitude.

```
const MapContainer = ({ currentPosition, setCurrentPosition, handleShow }) => {
  ...
    return (
      <Marker onClick={handleShow} position={currentPosition} />
    )
      ...
```

Finally, on the modal, just use the passed `currentPosition` props to display the data as necessary

```
function Example({ show, handleShow, handleClose, currentPosition }) {
  return (
    ...
    <Modal.Body>
      Latitude: {currentPosition.lat} Longitude: {currentPosition.lng}
    </Modal.Body>
    ...
  )
}
```

[image: Edit React Google Maps getCurrentPosition]